What is an alternative for Firebase dynamic links?
Firebase dyanmic links are deprecating.
Whether the options free or having charges? If yes then what will be the better option as per lowest charge?
if their any other solution then good to use it. Otherwise how we can developed? and It should be easy to migrate for a big android and flutter project.
I have checked about the flowlinks but didn't find their costing.

You might try out dynalinks - it allows you to create up to 5k links for free.
